# Javascript: Find most relevant strings in an array from substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array that includes names of people similar to this (but much larger):

```
let names = [
   "John Brown", 
   "Tristan Black", 
   "Carl Jobbs", 
   "Aidan Burrows", 
   "Taylor Joe"
];
```

Based on an input, I'm trying to return the most relevant results in the array. Currently I'm looping through the array of names and checking them like this:

```
if(name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
{
    console.log("Found match : " + name);
}
```

This is obviously not suitable for finding the most relevant search result as it finds any name with input in.

Ideally what I want to do is loop through the array of names and find the top 5 (in the sense that they are the most similar to the input) results.

How could I do this?

Comment: Define `most relevant`. The closest results, in terms of levenshtein distance?

Comment: Starting from how many chars? Usually you would want to start your `search` after more than 2 characters entered by the user

Comment: Are you familiar with [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: This might be of relevance to you: https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein

The Levenshtein distance provides a metric to determine the similarity or "relevance" of one string to another. You might find it useful to order the top 5 strings based on the Levenshtein distance of those strings from your input string

Comment: I've edited my array as I actually include the last name of each person in the name. Ideally what I would like to be able to do is if the input is Aid for example it will only display Aidan Burrows, but also if I search Burr it will only display Aidan Burrows (as that is his last name). Similarly if I searched Jo it would display both Carl Jobbs and Taylor Joe

Comment: Would that work with the levenshtein algorithm if they enter part of the persons last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this function should achieve what you need:

```js
function filterByName(input, nameArray) {
  
  return nameArray.filter(name => (name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())))
}

let names = ["John Brown", "Tristan Black", "Carl Jobbs", "Aidan Burrows", "Taylor Joe"];

console.log('Found for Aid:', filterByName('Aid', names))
console.log('Found for Burr:', filterByName('Burr', names))
console.log('Found for Jo:', filterByName('Jo', names))
```